# Convert float days to timedelta64[ns] in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, floating-point, timedelta

I have found this where 1,5 is 1,5 days

```
pd.to_timedelta('1,5')
```

But it gives me `0 days 00:00:00.000000015`

I needed this : `1 days 12:00:00.000000000`

How to convert float days to timedelta64[ns] in a pandas column dataframe please ?

Comment: `pd.to_timedelta(float('1,5'.replace(',', '.')), unit='d')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was this :

```
pd.to_timedelta('1.5 days')
```